# Google Maps RichMarker Event

Tags: google-maps, events, firefox

I have events working fine in Chrome and IE10 for Google Maps (APIv3) and RichMarkers. Problem is, the same code borks on Firefox19 with *event undefined*. So, this code works on Chrome and IE10...

```
google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'mouseover', function(event) {
        console.log(event);
});
```

But not on Firefox. Interestingly, attaching a CLICK event to the map object does work as  you'd expect. The event object is visible within the called function in all browsers. So, does anyone have any idea as to how to fix this? I really need to pass the event object onwards as I have funcs that use it for positioning and so on.

Normally, I'd get around this using jQuery to attach the events, but this is not an option here.

Cheers

CT

Answer (score 0):

There is no mouseover-event : http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/docs/reference.html

Apply the mouseover-event to the content of the marker(the content must be a node)

Comment: OK I've tried to do this, before passing the content to the RichMarker, with no apparent success. I guess its processing the element on handover to RichMarker. So I'll try applying the events after RichMarker init and see how that goes.